# How to format my y-axis tick values and my geom_text to show commas as thousands separator?

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting

I have the following codes running in R:

```
options(scipen=99)

sp <- ggplot(mydata2, aes(x=FY, y=PkgRev, fill=FY, label=PkgRev)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +  
geom_text(aes(label=PkgRev),size=3,position=position_dodge(width=0.9),vjust=-0.50)

sp

sp + facet_grid(Market ~ PropertyCode) +
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
 ggtitle('xxxxxxxx') +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 170100000, by=50000000), limits=c(0,170100000))
```

The above codes give me the following output (extract shown):

[image: image1]

I want the y-axis tick values to be separated by a comma to represent thousands and the same principle on the text showing the values on top of the bars.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scales package and add "labels = comma" to your scale_y_continuous()
See this post for the axis
[Thousand separator in label of x or y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191601/thousand-separator-in-label-of-x-or-y-axis)
And this for the geom_text
[including a comma separator for data labels in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427639/including-a-comma-separator-for-data-labels-in-ggplot)

so:

```
sp <- ggplot(mydata2, aes(x=FY, y=PkgRev, fill=FY, label=PkgRev)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label=comma(PkgRev)),size=3,
         position=position_dodge(width=0.9),vjust=-0.50)

sp + facet_grid(Market ~ PropertyCode) +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
     ggtitle('xxxxxxxx') +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 170100000, by=50000000), 
     limits=c(0,170100000), labels = comma)
```

should work